# Angular js 1.x importing / export modules with different IIFES in order to be able to use with webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am wondering what is the best way to proceed with this.

//directive.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

angular
    .module('my.dir', [])
    .directive('my-dir', MyDirDirective);

function MyDirDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: MyDirController
    }
}
})();
```

// controller.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

    angular
      .module('my.dir', [])
      .controller('MyDirController', MyDirController);

    function MyDirController() {

    }
})();
```

I have these two files and I want to to export them into a single index.js so I can then import the index.js to my main app.js in order load it as a dependency so that I can be able to use webpack.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

directive.js:

```
export function MyDirDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: MyDirController
    }
}
```

controller.js:

```
export function MyDirController() {

}
```

app.module.js:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import MyDirDirective from './directive';
import MyDirController from './controller';

export const myModule = angular.module('...', [])
      .directive('myDir', MyDirDirective)
      .controller('MyDirController', MyDirController)
      .name;
```

However, I suggest not exporting (and even registering `MyDirController`) unless you want to use it somewhere else.

You can also use [angular-ts-decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ts-decorators) if you are ok to use typescript.

Comment: Thanks for the reply as well.

Answer (score 0):

With webpack, you should be able to use ES6 classes. So the two files can be merged into a single file:

**my-directive.js**

```
export default function MyDirDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: MyDirController
  }
};

class MyDirController {
  constructor() {
    // code for constructor
  }

  // other methods
}
```

And then you can have another file for your module:

**dir-module.js**

```
import MyDirDirective from 'my-directive.js';

export default angular
  .module('my.dir', [])
  .directive('myDir', MyDirDirective);
```

And, in `index.js`, just import this module.

**index.js**

```
import 'dir-module.js';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! ;)

Comment: My problem is that this is an existing codebase and its quite large so going through each file and perform changes would be very time consuming.